# Side-by-side elements that stack if there is not enough horizontal space

Tags: css

Suppose I have two divs:

```
<div id="first">
    <h1>First Div</h1>
</div>
<div id="second">
    <h2>Second Div</h2>
</div>
```

I want to display them side-by-side.

[image: Side-by-side divs]

However, this is a site designed to work at many viewport sizes.  I want to specify a minimum width for these elements and let the browser worry about laying them out.  If there isn't enough horizontal space, I'd like these divs to stack vertically and take 100% of the horizontal space.

[image: Vertically stacked divs]

I've started with this:

```
#first {
  min-width: 15em;
  max-width: 100%;
}
#second {
  float: right;
  max-width: 10em;
}
```

Short of writing media queries, is there is a way to handle this with CSS?  (Modern CSS3 rules are fine, I'd just like to let the browser lay this out if possible.)

JSFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/p8z1zr2g/1/

If I had consistent sizes between the two, it wouldn't be that big of a deal.  One could wrap and all would be well.  It's the difference in sizing that's confusing me.

Comment: you can make them stack if  they do not fit, but you cant make them occupy `100%` of horizontal space without media queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes).

For example,

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#first {
  flex: 1 15em;
}
#second {
  flex: 1 10em;
}
```

Since the flex grow factor is set to 1, they will grow to fill the available space, whether they are at the same line or not.

```css
/* Layout */
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#first {
  flex: 1 15em;
}
#second {
  flex: 1 10em;
}

/* Debugging Colors */
body > * {
  outline: 2px solid #444;
}
body >:nth-child(1) {
  outline-color: #f0a;
}
body >:nth-child(2) {
  outline-color: #0fa;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
  <h1>First Div</h1>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.</p>
</div>
<div id="second">
  <h2>Second Div</h2>
  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I was about to propose the same upon flex-basis http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/pvxJNJ (upvoted)